# Como passo essa imagem como parâmetro?

Tags: javascript, html, parâmetros

A questão é a seguinte, como passo a imagem como parâmetro pra usar ela no javascript com tentei no código abaixo?

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="botao_1"class="bgbotaorank" style="background-image:url('twitter.png');"  onclick="muda_imagem('botao_1','twitter.png');">
</div>
<div id="botao_2" class="bgbotaorank" onclick="muda_imagem('botao_2','twitter.png');">
</div>
<div id="botao_3" class="bgbotaorank">
</div>
<div id="botao_4" class="bgbotaorank"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function muda_imagem(id, imagem) {
document.getElementById("botao_1").style.backgroundImage = "url('red.png')";
document.getElementById("botao_2").style.backgroundImage = "url('red.png')";
document.getElementById("botao_3").style.backgroundImage = "url('red.png')";
document.getElementById("botao_4").style.backgroundImage = "url('red.png')";
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = 'url(imagem)';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Passar como parâmetro não era o problema, e sim usar o parâmetro.

Veja a função ajustada:

```js
function muda_imagem(id, imagem) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imagem + ')';
}
```

```css
/*
 * Daqui pra baixo é só teste:
 */

div { width:180px;height:180px;background-color:#f90 }
```

```html
<div id="botao_1" onclick="muda_imagem('botao_1','https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOE9F.jpg');">
Clique-me</div>
```

Clique em "Executar" logo acima, e faça o teste.

Outro modo seria a função ser assim:

```
 document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = imagem;
```

E você chamá-la assim:

```
 muda_imagem( 'botao_1', 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOE9F.jpg)' );
```

Esta segunda seria útil se você quiser chamar tanto imagens com `url` como `data:` usando a mesma função (e quem sabe *gradients*, etc).